Advance Installer crashing when open dialog after upgrade
I used Advance Installer 18.1.1 and used to successfully created installer with that. Now we have changed the code signing method to use Azure Key Vault, and running the installer build via GitHub actions. so had to upgrade the Advance installer to the latest version (21.9)
I was able to successfully build the installer, but when run it, it crashes before opening the first dialog.
Opened the .aip file in Advance Installer, and tried to open the dialogs. Then I get this error message and closing it crashes Advance Installer software.

How should I fix this error and make the installer work fine?
Thank you in advance

This looks like a very Advanced Installer specific issue to me. Maybe you can try to contact their support team.
